# identify reason for executeQuery failure from exception in MariaDB?

Tags: mariadb-10.3

We can connect and execute queries in mariadb server using a mariaDB-connector-cpp (official connector from mariadb). As of now, no issues observed while connecting, executeQuery.
As per the sample code executeQuery reports failure by raising exceptions. Currently, we are displaying failure with info retrieved from e.what() call. Sample code available [here](https://github.com/mariadb-developers/todo-app-cpp/blob/main/tasks.cpp) (updateTaskStatus).

Exceptions raised for different reasons. We would like to look at the errorCodes & identify failure to take some action if the failure can be handled with retry (like connection down).

As per code in [Ref](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-cpp/blob/master/src/MariaDBException.cpp) exception is holding ErrorCode but there is no get function defined in SQLException class. All the possible error code are defined [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-error-codes/)

Please help. Also, please point us to any man/documentation for MariaDB connector exposed apis, as there is very less documentation on these.